# Can I list/edit/remove the "remembered" display settings for different multi-monitor setups?

Tags: macos, display, performance

I've had various single-external-monitor setups previously, and now I have two external monitors. MacOS seems to remember some previous ones and since one monitor takes slightly longer to wake up, it cycles through 2-3 previous setups before figuring out my current setup.

Is there a way to see the previously-remembered setups (perhaps a config file somewhere) that I can find and edit/remove the old setups from?

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect preferences to have this delay. I'd far more likely cable issues, slow reaction time by the displays (see if you can fix their input and not have it scan for viable signal from all inputs) or display firmware and not the macOS delaying things.

I can't tell you how to look and see if settings are remembered, so until someone else points out how this all is stored, I would install macOS on an external drive and you can boot from a 100% pristine system and convince yourself if this is a setting or just the way those displays work now.

That's my recommendation to nail this down now, at least.

If you have a super speedy connection on a brand new OS, then that will make it more imperative to know the details of how the OS tracks external displays and my hunch would be wrong.